# jquery slideToggle with siblings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to hide one div and show other div.

While hiding and showing other div, it should look like a slide, which can be achieved using [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) in jQuery.

Please suggest the necessary changes in my javascript to make div appear as a slide when clicked on 1 or 2 to show corresponding div in the table. Please find the complete example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0p7djjnc/8/).

When user clicks on 1 divOne12 should be shown and when user clicks 2 divTwo12 should appear and previous div should be hidden. How can i apply slideToggle() in the below javascript function.

Thanks.

Below is the javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navigateTest').click(function () {
        var t = $(this).data('target');
        $('#'+t).show().siblings('div').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: @AlexChar i believe this person is trying to get the divs to animate via sliding instead of just showing/hiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0p7djjnc/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('.navigateTest').click(function () {
        var t = $(this).data('target');
        $('#'+t).slideDown(500).siblings('div').slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks.By any change can we use slideToggle() ?    @Matt Kenefick.

Comment: Depends on what you want out of it. You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/0p7djjnc/10/  Which will toggle the selected cell open and closed, but the others will always close. Is this what you mean?

Comment: no..it should not close if i click to show the already selected div.It should work in the same way as your previous answer. http://jsfiddle.net/0p7djjnc/9/ .Thanks. @Matt Kenefick

Comment: Well, in that case you don't want slideToggle. slideToggle will close something that is open and open something that is closed, like in #10.